# Is it possible to keep adding methods inside an iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to keep adding a method such as `.next()` everytime it does not find a specific value. Is this possible in javascript?

Example:

right now this is what I have:

```
    $('.contenido').filter(function(){
        var data = $(this);
        var tableLength = data.children().children('tr').length;
        var table = data.children().children().children();
        var row = table.next().next().next().next().children();
        link = row.attr('href');

    })
```

link returns the href of `row`. But lets say there are more rows with the href attr. How can I loop to keep adding `.next()` to `row` until it finds one with the href attr?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? What is the purpose of adding next when it doesn't find a specific value?

Comment: what do you mean by `next()`? `next()` is a selector method to get the *next* element

Comment: Im building a scraper for a page that is not using any class nor id names. So I need to find href links for each tr in a table. I want it to iterate through all the rows in search for the .attr('href). The example in the OP is just a general example for what I want to achieve.

Comment: Don't you think simply doing `var html = document.body.innerHTML, matches = html.match(/href=["']http.*?["']/)` will be easier? Returns an array with all the matches... After that, in a for loop, simply reassign each item: `item = item.replace(/href=["']/, '').slice(-1)` & you have your links.

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to iterate through all the rows in search for the .attr('href).

Try

```
$('.contenido tr').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('[href]').length == 0){
        return true;
    }
    link = row.attr('href');
    return false;
});
```

[**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) will *iterate* through the selected elements. `return true` will break out of the current iteration. Therefore, the code for href wont execute unless an `href` element is found. Finally, when it sets the `href`, `return false` will exit the iterations entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Try an while loop

```
while (i < 10) {
    text += "The number is " + i;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Although using a while loop is a valid method, this answer does not demonstrate any effort to integrate it into the code provided in the question.